# Storing overlap add values in an array

Tags: c, arrays, addition, store

I have a rather easy question, but I can't find an easy solution for it.
The thing is like this, I have a signal let's say x which length's is 32.`x[32]`. And this array I get, at each step, the values for a real time signal . At step one I get [0:31] values, step 2 [1:32], step 3 [2:33] and so on. To get the final signal I want to overlap add this values and store them into an array. The way I try to this is declare an array of a certain length, let's say 150. `xfinal[150]`.
And then, to fill xfinal I do this.

```
Step 1. xfinal[0:31] = x[0:31].
Step 2. xfinal[1:31] = xfinal[1:31] + x[0:30].
    xfinal[32] = x[31];
Step 3. xfinal[2:32] = xfinal[2:32] + x[0:30].
    xfinal[33] = x[31];
```

And so on. This way after 33 signals every value in x_final is going to be the sum of 32.

The code I wrote in C to do this is (it is a bit more complicated because x is a frame so I have to copy pixel by pixel.

```
void Overlapadd ( float **final_X, float **all_frames_X, int add_index,int w, int h)
{
    for (int i=0; i< frame_size ; i++) {  // for every pixel

        for( int j=add_index; j<add_index+32; j++){
            final_X[j][i] += all_frames_S[j-add_index][i];
        }

    }

    add_index++;
}
```

The problem with this code is that when I run it for a big period of time the `final_X` array will fill and `final_X[add_index+32]` will go out of the memory. This is why I want to store it in a circular way. So when I reach the end I go back to 0. The problem is that when I reach a point in `final_X`, let's say add_index=60. So `final_X[add_index]` will be the sum of 32 frames, but `final_X[add_index+1]` will be the some of only 31 frames, `final_X[add_index+2]` will be the some of only 30 frames and so on. And this values are important to me because they help me get the new values by adding the new x.

I don't know if I made myself clear, probably not, but I'm hoping for some help. So the question is how can I overlap add the signals and store them in a vector for a long period.
[image]

Comment: There is two things I find hard to understand from your question: 1) While your explanation and sketch treats `final_X` as a 1-dimensional array, your code uses it as a 2-dimensional one. 2) It is not clear how you determine the "out of memory" condition. Can you include the allocation steps?

Comment: I've treated final_X as a 1-dimensional array to make it easier to follow. x itself is an array, so final_x will be an array of array but the principle is the same. By going out of memory I mean that I allocate 150 frames for final_X and at some point I would call final_X[151].

Answer (score 0):

You can use modular arithmetic for that at the cost of one extra variable in the innermost loop to serve as counter, while the other will serve as position index.

```
#define FINAL_X_LEN 150

void Overlapadd(float **final_X, float **all_frames_X, int add_index)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < frame_size; i++)
        for(int j = add_index, int k = 0; k < 32; j = (j+1)%FINAL_X_LEN)
            final_X[j][i] += all_frames_S[k][i];

}
```

Here, `k` is used to count iterations, and `j` is the real position you are indexing.

Be careful with `add_index++;` in the end of `Overlapadd`, this will most likely not work the way you expect. Values are passed by copy, so `add_index++` is only incrementing your local copy of `add_index`, this change will not be visible to the caller. You must pass `add_index` as a pointer if you want to simulate pass-by-reference.

Also, note that the way you organized the code is not very friendly for caching. `final_X[j][i] += ...` is bad because `j` is changed in every iteration of the innermost loop, this breaks spatial locality and increases cache miss rate. If you access nearby positions in your array, you can increase cache hit time and overall program performance. I suggest copying every frame for each position `j`, and not copying a frame at a time for every position `j` (which is what you're doing right now). In this case, this is as simple as swapping the order of the loops:

```
void Overlapadd(float **final_X, float **all_frames_X, int add_index)
{
    for(int j = add_index, int k = 0; k < 32; j = (j+1)%FINAL_X_LEN)
        for (int i = 0; i < frame_size; i++)
            final_X[j][i] += all_frames_S[k][i];

}
```

Comment: I'm not sure I completely understand how this works, but I will give it a try :D. One thing I am concerned about is that it will keep adding and adding, and I'm only interested to have 32 frames at all time. What I mean is that it will go through the vector the first time, but when it comes again, it adds to the previous value. So the first iteration at position 33 for instance I will have 32 frames, the second I will have 64 (because it keeps the first 32 values) and so on..

Comment: And thanks for the loop advice, I was actually wondering which way would it be faster: frame by frame, or pixel from each frame.

Comment: @CRS so what should happen when it wraps around? You want to start over, i.e., you want to set `final_X` to 0 on that position before adding? If that's just it, an `if` is all you need.

Answer (score 0):

I don't fully understand what's your aim, but for circular adding, you must just have a continuous index variable using with modulo:

```
int x[32];
int xfinal[32];

for (int i=0; i<32; i++) // initialize xfinal with 0
    xfinal[i] = 0;

int iter = 100; // doing additions e.g. 100 times

for (int i=0; i<iter; i++)
    for (int j=0; j<32; j++)
        xfinal[(j+i)%32] += x[j]; // index of xfinal remains inside 0-31
```

Also note, that your `add_index++` in `Overlapaddd()` has no remaining effect!

**Edit:**

This is what my solution does:

[image]

The outer circle is xfinal, the inner is x. The inner circle rotates clockwards with `i` running to `iter`, and the outer does `+=` the underlying cell. At the first iteration, the inner circle is unrotated relatively to fully 0 initialized outer circle, so outer circle becomes = inner circle (= your Step 1). And so on...

Comment: In this case wouldn't it just add the same x 100 times? Or for me at every iteration X is different. I agree, I made a mistake with add_index, I wil declare it a pointer.

Comment: I can see it now. Thanks for explanation, but still doesn't help me too much because I also need the values for 100 x_final stored.

Answer (score 0):

Ok so one thing I thought of is this.

So far from frame 33 at each iteration I get a good value for x_final. So I was thinking after I get enough values for x_final to copy the frames after that position and put them at the beginning of the vector.
So let's say x_final has 170 length. `x_final[170]`

```
int curr_pos;

// if I reached frame 132 it means that values from 32-131 already have a 32 frame sum in them

if(add_index == 132) // I have 100 good values of x_final already - x_final[32:131]
{
    for( int j=add_index; j<add_index+32; j++){
        for (int i=0; i< (w*h) ; i++) {
            x_final[add_index-132][i] = x_final[j][i]; //copy the rest at the beginning of the vector
        }
    }
    curr_pos = 0;
}
else
    curr_pos = add_index;



  //Overlap add the new 32 frames 
  for( int j=curr_pos; j<curr_pos+32; j++){
        for (int i=0; i< (w*h) ; i++) {
        x_final[j][i] += all_frames_S[j-curr_pos][i];
    }
}

   // prepare vector for next iteration
   for (int i=0; i< (w*h) ; i++) {
        x_final[curr_pos+32][i] = 0;
    }
```

Any flaws in this approach?